# Eslint --fix removes type annotation

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have project with typescript + eslint stack.

Trouble with rule `@typescript-eslint/typedef`:
When i try to use command `eslint --fix` type annotation has been removed:

example:

```
formCtrlName: string = '';
```

After command `eslint --fix` i will get next code:

```
formCtrlName = '';
```

and error:

```
26:3   error    expected formCtrlName to have a type annotation  @typescript-eslint/typedef
```

Rules for eslint:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint',
    'eslint-plugin-tsdoc',
    'simple-import-sort',
    'unicorn',
    'jsdoc'
  ],
  // camelcase, indent, no-array-constructor, and no-unused-vars are all
  // busted when using TypeScript at the moment. When you use this plugin, you're
  // forced to turn off the base rules from ESLint and turn on the TypeScript-friendly
  // variant that comes with @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin.
  rules: {
    // tsdoc rules
    'tsdoc/syntax': 'error',
    'jsdoc/require-param-description': 2,
    'jsdoc/require-param-name': 2,
    'jsdoc/require-param': 2,
    'jsdoc/check-alignment': 2,
    'jsdoc/check-indentation': 2,
    'jsdoc/check-param-names': 2,
    'jsdoc/check-values': 2,
    'jsdoc/no-types': 2,
    // using a single import statement per module
    'no-duplicate-imports': ['error', { 'includeExports': true }],
    // avoid using methods on console
    'no-console': ['error', { allow: ['warn', 'error'] }],
    // camelcase interference fix.
    camelcase: 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': [2, { properties: 'never' }],
    // indent interference fix.
    indent: 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['error', 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
    // no-array-constructor interference fix.
    'no-array-constructor': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor': 'error',
    // no-unused-vars interference fix.
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': [
      'error',
      {
        allowExpressions: true,
        allowTypedFunctionExpressions: true,
        allowHigherOrderFunctions: true,
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': ['warn', { 'ignoreRestArgs': false }],
    // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    "no-magic-numbers": "off",
    // for future release
    // '@typescript-eslint/no-extra-non-null-assertion': ['warn'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-magic-numbers': ['error', {
      'ignoreNumericLiteralTypes': true,
      'ignoreReadonlyClassProperties': true,
      'ignoreEnums': true,
      'ignoreArrayIndexes': true,
      'ignore': [0, 1, 2, 10, 100, 1000]
    }],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition': ['error'],
    // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    'no-unused-expressions': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': ['error', { 'functions': true, 'classes': true }],
    '@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands': 'error',
    // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
    'semi': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/typedef': [
      'error',
      {
        'arrowParameter': false,
        'variableDeclaration': true,
      }
    ],
    'typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 'off',
    // Enforces naming conventions for everything across a codebase
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
      "error",
      {
        "selector": "default",
        "format": ["camelCase"]
      },

      {
        "selector": "variable",
        "format": ["camelCase", "UPPER_CASE"]
      },
      {
        "selector": "parameter",
        "format": ["camelCase"],
        "leadingUnderscore": "allow"
      },
      {
        "selector": "variable",
        "types": ["boolean"],
        "format": ["camelCase"],
        "prefix": ["is", "should", "has", "can", "did", "will"]
      },
      {
        "selector": "typeLike",
        "format": ["PascalCase"]
      }
    ],
    // disable eslint sort imports
    'sort-imports': 'off',
    'import/order': 'off',
    // checks all import declarations and verifies that all imports are first sorted by the used member syntax
    // and then alphabetically by the first member or alias name
    'simple-import-sort/sort': 'error',
    // check file names for kebabCase
    'unicorn/filename-case': ['error', { "case": "kebabCase" }],
  },
};
```

How can i fix it?
When i try to use rule `@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types` i get conflict whith rule `@typescript-eslint/typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/typedef
```

before the code with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```json
'typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 'off',
```

...you're missing the "at" sign. Fix it like this and it should work:

```json
'@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 'off',
```

Comment: Ampersand is the "and" sign i.e. "&". I think you mean the "at" symbol i.e. "@"/

Comment: @AdamHarte Whoops. Fixed, thanks.